# Why Is This Code Working When Directly Manipulating Dom Instead Of When Variables Are Made First And Then Dom Is Manipulated? (Javascript))

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
//In the code below I'm using the open weather API to make a simple weather app

const showWeatherData = (weatherData) => {
  document.getElementById("city-name").innerText = weatherData.name;
  document.getElementById("weather-type").innerText = weatherData.weather[0].main;
  document.getElementById("temp").innerText = weatherData.main.temp;
  document.getElementById("min-temp").innerText = weatherData.main.temp_min;
  document.getElementById("max-temp").innerText = weatherData.main.temp_max;
};
```

The above code snippet is working....

But the code snippet below doesn't work:

```
const cityName = document.getElementById("city-name");
const weatherType = document.getElementById("weather-type");
const temp = document.getElementById("temp");
const minTemp = document.getElementById("min-temp");
const maxTemp = document.getElementById("max-temp");




const showWeatherData = (weatherData) => {
  //CODE GOES HERE
  cityName.innerText = weatherData.name;
  weatherType.innerText = weatherData.weather[0].main;
  temp.innerText = weatherData.main.temp;
  minTemp.innerText = weatherData.main.temp_min;
  maxTemp.innerText = weatherData.main.temp_max;
}
```

They both are the same so how come its not working?

I know that this might be a newbie question...

But this is my first JavaScript course, I was expecting that you could make variables and manipulate DOM but is this not the case?

Comment: What error are you getting in the console when it does not work?

Comment: your code should work, Im assuming is not becuz you are calling your function before the HTML finishes rendering